# Android: продажа приложений

Tags: android, google-play, работа

Написав игрушку для андройда, есть ли возможность заработать на маркете и избавиться от постоянной работы?
т.е. чтоб работать на себя
?
какие трудности ожидают начинающего кракозябра? (не в плане кодинга)

Comment: кто нибудь знает что это?
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/
и есть ли аналоги, я так понимаю это библиотека упрощающая программирование?

Comment: >как оно с продажами? 

С продажами хорошо, а без них совсем плохо

Comment: добавлю подвопрос: в каком проценте случаев игры хватает для заработка на жизнь (даёт хотя-бы одну зелёную тысячу в месяц)?

Comment: Это все индивидуально. Точной статистики не будет никогда.

Comment: @danpetruk я думаю, что одна из 1000 дает $1k в месяц

Answer (score 7):

Нереально, особенно с игрой. Для Андроид пишут игры огромные корпорации с приличными бюджетами, с гениальными дизайнерами и проч. время одиночек закончилось года 2-3 назад. Если повезет то наскребете 2-3 штуки вечнозеленых за год.

Если не игра, то шансы еще есть.

Comment: Ну... имхо... (если уйти от идеи зарабатывать только таким образом) то если ваять игрушки под кофе и девушек вечером после работы, то 2-3К в принципе не так и плохо, для подработки... за них можно например нанять нормального дизайнера пару раз или купить у молодого композитора прикольный трек на озвучку. 

Если есть желание - почему не попробовать))

Comment: @Silverlce Вы только забываете "если повезет". Как показывает опыт - большинству не везет.

Answer (score 5):

Написав одну игрушку - вряд ли. Очень небольшой шанс, что повезет.

Напишите 10-15 игрушек и смотрите. Возможно, что за 9 из них Вы не получите и доллара.

Какие ещё проблемы? Может оказаться, что Вы живете не в той стране, не родились не в тот день недели или ноутбук имеет мало гигагерц. Поменьше думайте об этом:)

Answer (score 5):

Ружье, может, выстрелить в любой момент во все времена. Лучше заниматься этим для начала как хобби. Далее ориентироваться по ситуации. Если долго что,то делать, момент озарения придет,правда, раньше придут отчаяние и желание бросить все. Надо вспомнить историю полковника Сандерса основателя известного кафе.. кто не знает почитайте.. у него было 1006 отказов, прежде чем пришел успех..дорога возникает под ногами идущего

Comment: Для тех кто в танке: полковник Сандерс основатель сети фастфуд ресторанов Kentucky Fried Chicken (KFC). Конечно, же это красивая легенда, но увы как и любая легенда весьма далека от реалий. Тем не менее плюсану, поскольку *дорогу осилит идущий*

Answer (score 3):

Согласен с предыдущими авторами вцелом. Раньше, когда ниши были еще свободны можно было выстрелить, сейчас же это гораздо сложнее. Взять например PowerAMP - лучший аудиоплеер, написанный одним человеком, но написанный не в 2012 и 2011, а ранее, когда плееров было не так много или почти не было во все. Доходы автора PowerAMP более 100к баксов в месяц на момент его интервью(по-моему 2011 год). Но это топ платных приложений почти во всех странах, где доступен стор. Сейчас ниш меньше, но можно брать качеством, что касается приложений. В играх как уже говорили - все иначе. Во-первых нужна команда или хотя бы классный дизайнер, если вы хотите, чтобы игра приносила более-менее стабильный доход, ну а иначе - все гораздо сложнее и зависит от идеи, реализации, обновлений и прочего, поэтому довольно случайно. Думаю порядка 100-300к в месяц будет нормой. Но уверен, все возможно, так что сложно сказать неверняка.

**UPDATE**
Пишите свои проекты и набирайтесь опыта. Это интересно и в конечном итоге приведет вас к цели. Главное правильно их ставить. Но не обольщайтесь времени на это нужно не мало, а желания еще больше.

Answer (score 3):

Пилю четвертый месяц полновесный 3D движок для мобильных платформ и 3D tower defence/шутер c видом сверху на нем с несколькими оригинальными идеями которые пока вроде никто не представлял в жанре. Сейчас добавляю стенсильные тени из Doom 3 через Carmack reverse, делаю рендеринг крови через карты нормалей и лазерные лучи через bloom shader.

С художниками/3D моделлерами/композиторами/озвучкой работаю в основном через договора о будущих процентах с продаж.

Дело это на любителя, требует много свободного времени, знаний математики/алгоритмов 3D графики и продвигается очень медленно, к тому же в процессе разработки не приносит почти ни копейки денег никому из участников(никто из моих знакомых не горит желанием финансировать разработки игр). С другой стороны там уже тысяч 40 строк кода и 300 страниц дизайн документов может и сработает чем черт не шутит.

В процессе очень круто помогают примеры от производителей видеочипов вроде Adreno SDK, PowerVR SDK, NVIDIA Tegra SDK(мануал по архитектуре процессоров серии Tegra занимает 2000 страниц) и горы бесплатных научных статей по 3D графике от зарубежных университетов(все на английском языке, на русском языке очень мало информации по этой теме).

В целом согласен с предыдущими авторами что для того чтобы получить гарантированный вменяемый доход от мобильной игры нужно либо поставить на рынок нечто действительно уникальное и стоящее на как можно большее число платформ либо 10-20 средненьких поделок. Я работаю по первому варианту из любви к искусству.

P.S. На том API из комментариев(libgdx) можно сделать простую игру-поделку, но не более того. Шансы что она выстрелит стремятся к нулю. Там не хватает поддержки теней, десятка моделей освещения, генератора градиентных шумов, вменяемой поддержки процедурного текстурирования, пост процессинг эффектов, пары десятков шейдеров и.т.д и.т.п по списку, оно написано на Java(холивар?) и очень далеко от совершенства как и большинство Open Source движков.

Comment: Зря плюсуете, а Вы автор зря обижаете libgdx. Пара примеров "игр-поделок" на данном движке:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bithack.apparatus
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nimblygames.bumbledore

Comment: У каждого своя специализация - здесь как и в любых продажах надо искать свою уникальную нишу. @igumnov ищет ее в продвинутом движке (сомневаюсь конечно), кто-то в другом, кто-то "простреливает" рынок во всех направлениях в надежде случайно нащупать свое место.

Comment: Да понятно, речь о заявлении автора ответа касательно libgdx и того, что игры на нем не выстреливают. Хм, ну да 750к загрузок по 89 рублей - это так, ерунда.

Comment: @DroidAlex 2 игры-вина на 23000 [закачек][1]
последней  версии движка. КПД 1 к 11.500. Это если не учитывать того факта что логика Apparatus сделана на Box2D, а во второй игре вообще тошнотворные спрайты с насекомыми, хотя на дворе 2013 год.
P.S. Вопрос куда делись остальные 11.498 человек которые скачали это? Клепают очередной мега хит?  

@Barmaley Я не делаю ничего продвинутого/нового просто комбинирую в одном проекте свои версии уже описанных кем-то до меня технологий/алгоритмов как и остальные разработчики других движков.

 [1]: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/downloads/list

Comment: @igumnov Какое кпд? Что это за кпд(отношение скачек на количество успешных игр) вообще, позвольте? :) Это странно. Речь о другом совсем. Вообщем, смысл не в движке, а в руках и идеи. А бокс2д там явашный скорее всего, биндинг. И смысл моего утверждение - опровержение вашего, якобы на данном движке делают хеллоуворлды только. Что-то вы немного не в ту степь мысль направляете. Обычно если человек не прав ему хватает сил это признать:) Без обид только.